# On invertibility of ergodic averages

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $x$ be invertible unbounded operator affiliated operator to the $\mathrm{II_{1}}$ factor $(M,\tau)$. Under which condition on $x$, the iterates also $1+\sigma(x)+\cdots+\sigma^{n}(x)$ are invertible for all $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$? Where, $\sigma$ $\in$ $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$? Here invertibility means kernel is trivial.

Comment: On invertibility of editing titles!

Comment: "Under which conditions...?" is more of a fishing expedition than a well thought out question ...

Comment: I removed the exclamation title from the title. (I'd like to convince OP to find a less depressing username too...)